# Track GitHub session on the server

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol, octokit-js

I am writing a language server that sometimes needs to access data from a GitHub repository. I am following [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/github-authentication-sample) to obtain GitHub authentication. The sample is based on client-side code, so I'm wondering how I would provide the authenticated GitHub session to the language server code. I know I can send messages from client to server, but I would need to be able to keep the session(s) in-mem for use during diagnostics, completions, doc symbols, etc. Is there a way to track the sessions in the server?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the sample code, an authentication token is obtained in the [`setOctokit()` method in `src/credentials.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/fdd3bb95ce8e38ffe58fc9158797239fdf5017f1/github-authentication-sample/src/credentials.ts#L17):

> ```js
> const session = await vscode.authentication.getSession(GITHUB_AUTH_PROVIDER_ID, SCOPES, { createIfNone: false });
>
> if (session) {
>   this.octokit = new Octokit.Octokit({
>       auth: session.accessToken
>   });
>
>   return;
> }
> ```

That should mean it is possible to do the following:

1. The client runs `const session = await vscode.authentication.getSession(GITHUB_AUTH_PROVIDER_ID, SCOPES, { createIfNone: false });`
2. The client sends `session.accessToken` to the server
3. The server can then initialize Octokit with this token to log into the GitHub API

Comment: The problem is that not only do I need to send it to the server, I need to be able to track it in the server so it's available when needed during all the different operations the server performs. I'm not sure how I can do that on the server reliably. I can't find anything on session states in an LSP server.